# Adding noise to nonlinear control system using NDSolve

Tags: equation-solving, random, control-systems

I have a nonlinear control system

```
system = {x'[t] == u[t] m[t], 
 WhenEvent[And[Mod[t, 9], x[t] < 100], m[t] -> x[t]], 
 WhenEvent[u[t] == 0, m[t] -> 10],  x[t /; t <= 0] == 0, 
 m[t /; t <= 0] == 1, u[t /; t <= 0] == 0};

control = {e[t] == xref - x[t], 
 WhenEvent[Mod[t, \[Tau]], 
 u[t] -> kp (k1 Sign[e[t]] - k2 Sign[e'[t]])], 
 e[t /; t <= 0] == xref};
 params = {kp -> 1, td -> 1, \[Tau] -> 0.5, xref -> 810, k1 -> 11/2, k2 -> 9/2};
```

which I simulate using `NDSolve`

```
 sol = NDSolve[{system, control} /. params, {x, m, u}, {t, 0, 60}, 
  DiscreteVariables -> {u, m}];
```

I would like to add random noise to the system, but so far nothing seems to work. Using `RandomReal[NormalDistribution[]]` is problematic, as it only samples once for `NDSolve`. Using `WienerProcess` with `ItoProcess` also does not seem to work, as the system contains discrete variables. I cannot convert it to a state space model, as `StateSpaceModel` only works for linear systems.

Comment: do I understand correctly, that you would like `x'[t] == u[t] m[t] + rn[t]`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can suggest you to add noise like the following!

```
noise[n_] := noise[n] = RandomReal[{-10, 10}];
MyNoise1[t_?NumericQ] :=1.5 Evaluate@With[{dt = .4},
    noise[Floor[t/dt]] Sin[2 Pi Mod[t, dt]/dt]^2];
```

or you can use something like this

```
sigma = 4.5;
{start, end} = {0, 60};
n = 240;
MyNoise2 = Interpolation@Join[{{start, 0.}}, 
Rest@Table[{t, RandomReal@NormalDistribution[0, sigma]}, {t, 
   start, end, (end- start)/(n - 1)}]];
```

The noise looks like the following

[image]

Now we add the noise like this

```
With[{v = MyNoise1},
     system = {x'[t] == u[t] m[t] + v[t], 
     WhenEvent[And[Mod[t, 9], x[t] < 100], m[t] -> x[t]], 
     WhenEvent[u[t] == 0, m[t] -> 10], x[t /; t <= 0] == 0, 
     m[t /; t <= 0] == 1, u[t /; t <= 0] == 0}];
```

[image]

Comment: nice answer +1!

Comment: @ruebenko Thx! Finding the sensitivity of the response with respect to such random noise will be great.

Comment: I have never tried that, you could give it a go with `ParameticNDSolve` I guess. I'd use a parameter for the noise and compute the derivative.

Comment: Great, that seems to work well. However, I had to increase `MaxSteps -> 30000` to be able to plot it?

Answer (score 4):

Another way to generate the noise would be to use `RandomVariate`.

```
noise = Interpolation[Thread[{Range[0, 60, 0.5], 
Join[{0}, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 120]]}], t]
```

This is how the noise looks.

[image]

Then everything follows exactly as the answer by PlatoManiac. (assuming that the noise enters the system through the input)

```
With[{v = noise}, system = {x'[t] == u[t] m[t] + v, 
WhenEvent[And[Mod[t, 9], x[t] < 100], m[t] -> x[t]], 
WhenEvent[u[t] == 0, m[t] -> 10], x[t /; t <= 0] == 0, 
m[t /; t <= 0] == 1, u[t /; t <= 0] == 0}];
```

etc

And the plot of x[t].

[image]

Comment: It seems that the noise value is constant for different values of `t`, or at least when I try to plot it?

Comment: Are you plotting noise =... and getting a constant value?

Comment: No, when I plot `x[t]` and `e[t]` the segments between events/state changes are straight lines. This shows up clearer when you plot from 0-30 instead of 0-60. Is it possible that it should be `v[t]` instead of just `v`?

Comment: v is correct not v[t]. My guess that it appears to be joined by straight lines  is because Interpolation is used? Not sure. But the noise value does change from instant to instant.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I increased the $\sigma$ of the distribution and I can see the changes.